# Having issue importing py file in Flask

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

I am having issues when importing py files in flask.  Here are how my files are structured:

Flask: /var/www/html/flask_app/flask.py

Current location of python script: /var/www/html/flask_app/python/IP/ip.py

Desired location of python script: /scripts/python/IP/ip.py

I would like to move my script from www directory and create a new folder in /. I am having issues when after I move, i can't seem to import it and get 500 error message.

Please see below:

```
// flask.py   
@app.route('/ipcheck', methods=['POST'])
def ip_check():    
    from python.IP import ip
    return ip.check_ip_range()

// Above works when python folder is in same directory.  However when I move python folder to /scripts/, I get Error 500.

// Flask.py after folder move - should import from /scripts/pyton/IP/ip.py

@app.route('/ipcheck', methods=['POST'])
def ip_check():
    sys.path.append('/scripts/')     
    from python.IP import ip
    return ip.check_ip_range()
```

How do I import ip.py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs to be in your Python path. If you don't want it in `www` folder, then install in path where other Python libraries are installed on your system. Otherwise add that location to the path before importing like so:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/scripts/python/")
```

Even so, you wouldn't import it from `python` unless that python folder has an `__init__.py` folder in it to make it a package (unless that *is* your system Python path). So in this case you'd just do:

```
from IP import ip
```

Assuming you appended it to system path dynamically as shown above.

Comment: Yes, I am doing sys,path.append but it is breaking my Flask.  I created a test.py file and was able to import ip.py and run the script on my Linux box.  The issue is, for some reason, Flask does not like this import.  If i move ip.py to same dir as flask.py, it works.

Comment: If you put it into another folder, you have to make it a package in order to import from that folder, i.e. add an `__init__.py` file to the folder.

Comment: @ Arthur Dent I have init in every folder including /

Comment: Thanks.  I will have to change my file structure.